# Java regular expression: escaping multi-lines comment containing the caracter $

Tags: regex, java-11

```java
    final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"");

    @Test
    public void parseCsvTest() {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        Matcher m = null;
        String csv="\"foo$\n" +  "bar\"";
        try {
            
            m = PATTERN.matcher(csv);
            while (m.find()) {
                m.appendReplacement(result, m.group().replaceAll("\\R+", ""));
            }
            m.appendTail(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String escaped_csv = result.toString();
        log.info(escaped_csv);
    }
```

With `String csv="\"foo\n" +  "bar\"";`
I'm getting the expected result that is: "foobar"

But with `String csv="\"foo$\n" +  "bar\"";` (notice the $ char after foo), the pattern doesn't identify the group. Note: $ is a char, not the "end of line symbol", despite it can be followed by a "end of line symbol".

Tried with `PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*^$?\"");` without success. Will return foo and bar in 2 lines

Any ideas ?

Comment: `"...foo\\$..."`

Comment: I can't manipulate de csv value: it is received as it from another system

Comment: Sorry I also did not see that $ is not part of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Got it work with: `Pattern.compile("\"*[^$]|\"[^\"]*\"");`

**Results**

`csv = "\"foo\n" +  "bar\n" +  "doe\"" => foobardoe`

`csv = "\"foo$\n" +  "bar\n" +  "doe\"" => foo$bardoe`

`csv = "\"foo$\n" +  "bar$\n" +  "doe\"" => foo$bar$doe`

`csv = "\"foo$\n" +  "bar$\n" +  "doe$\"" => foo$bar$doe$`

Comment: Complicated, and `\"*` matching no double quote is cumbersome, I hope no data errors happen.